# link_to with customized devise routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, link-to

Cheers! I have in routes code like this:

```
 user_photo GET    /users/:user_id/photos/:id(.:format)      photos#show
```

And I have a link_to helper:

```
= link_to 'Show', ...
```

How can I link it to show photo uploaded by current user?

```
user_photo_path
```

doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
link_to 'Show', user_photo_path(@user, @photo)
```

(This is assuming you have the @user and @photo objects available to you in your view - set these in your controller)

For more see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects

Comment: Changed to smth like this:
`= link_to 'Show', user_photo_path(current_user, photo)`
Because there was |photo| iterator, thank you!

Comment: Good - glad it worked.  Should use the path helpers where possible otherwise it gets messy quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

We can specify our own path.

```
<%= link_to "show", "/users/"+user_id.to_s+"/photos/"+id.to_s %>
```

Comment: `= link_to "Show", "/users/#{current_user.id}/photos/#{photo.id}"` works fine for me, thank you!